# resetStateMachine to set initial state and id

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

It seems that doing the following will make the id null

```
# before reset, this will log the id set when state machine was created using stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(stateMachineId)
log.info(String.format("Before reset, current state: %s, id: %s", stateMachine.getState().getId().toString(), stateMachine.getId()));

# resetting the state machine
stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(access -> access
                            .resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(correctState, null, null, null)));

# after reset, this will log id as null
log.info(String.format("After reset, state: %s, id: %s", stateMachine.getState().getId().toString(), stateMachine.getId()));
```

Is there a way to preserve or set the id again?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that there's another signature for DefaultStateMachineContext constructor:

```
/**
     * Instantiates a new default state machine context.
     *
     * @param state the state
     * @param event the event
     * @param eventHeaders the event headers
     * @param extendedState the extended state
     * @param historyStates the history state mappings
     * @param id the machine id
     */
    public DefaultStateMachineContext(S state, E event, Map<String, Object> eventHeaders, ExtendedState extendedState,
            Map<S, S> historyStates, String id) {
        this(new ArrayList<StateMachineContext<S, E>>(), state, event, eventHeaders, extendedState, historyStates, id);
    }
```

so, this following worked for me!

```
stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(access -> access
                            .resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(correctState, null, null, null, null, stateMachine.getId())));
```

Answer (score 1):

To call resetStateMachine may leave your state machine in an inconsistent state. I'm using a state machine with JPA persist and resetting the state machine made me lose the extended state of the state machine, even thou I set the extended state in the resetStateMachine function.

For me, just stopping and starting the state machine to reset it, is the better solution.

Version 3.0

```
stateMachine.stopReactively().block();
stateMachine.startReactively().block();
```

Earlier versions

```
stateMachine.stop();
stateMachine.start();
```